# How to count a file download with button clicks using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, count, download

I have a webpage which helps download files from database. I want to count the how many times the download button has been clicked and display it on my webpage with unique id. This is my download webpage. Any help will do please

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="media">
<img src="./images/<?= $mainImage; ?>" alt="PowerBeatz" width="300" height="300" />
<div class="media-body">
<h5 class="mt-0"><span class="title"><?php echo $row['song']; ?></span></h5>
<?php echo $row['artist']; ?>
<div class="play">
<a href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['song_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> </a>
</div>
<div>
<p>Total Downloads: </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my file.php script and I need a script to show me how to alter it to display the count results on the download page, please any help

```
<?php
require_once './includes/connection.php';
$conn = dbConnect('read');
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$songid = $_GET['id'];
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM homemp3 WHERE song_id ='.$songid;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$mp3 = 'homemp3/' .$row['filename'];
// Get a date and timestamp
if(file_exists($mp3)) {
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .basename($mp3). '"' );
header('Content-length: '. filesize($mp3));
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
readfile($mp3);
header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
exit;
}

My database structure...
song_id    filename    song   album_art    artist    downloads
   x          x           x      x            x         x
```

Comment: write to a db table inside file.php record the counts with the song_id, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Indenting is your best friend.

Answer (score 2):

Each time the file is accessed, could be in file.php, do an UPDATE in MYSQL with the file id's row, update a column called 'downloads' or something. Update it, adding 1 to it.

Like this:

```
 UPDATE songs SET downloads=downloads+1 WHERE id = song_id
```

The on the above page, you'd get the downloads column and echo it after 'Total Downloads'.

Not knowing whether you are using some framework you could leverage for this, if you are just writing straight PHP from scratch you could use the above like this. Here is an updated downloads.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
try {
// Database connection
require_once './includes/connection.php';
$conn = dbConnect('read');
// Sql query from table
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$songid = $_GET['id'];
}
$sql = 'SELECT filename, album_art, downloads, song, song_id, artist FROM homemp3 WHERE 
song_id ='.$songid;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

<!doctype html>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="media">
<img src="./images/<?= $mainImage; ?>" alt="PowerBeatz" width="300" height="300" />
<div class="media-body">
<h5 class="mt-0"><span class="title"><?php echo $row['song']; ?></span></h5>
<?php echo $row['artist']; ?>
<div class="play">
<a href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['song_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> </a>
</div>
<div>
<p>Total Downloads: <?php echo $row['downloads']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then file.php

```
<?php
require_once './includes/connection.php';
$conn = dbConnect('read');
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$songid = $_GET['id'];
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM homemp3 WHERE song_id ='.$songid;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$mp3 = 'homemp3/' .$row['filename'];

// Update download count
$conn = dbConnect('read');
$update = 'UPDATE homemp3 SET downloads=downloads+1 WHERE song_id ='.$songid;
$downloads = $conn->query($update);

// Get a date and timestamp
if(file_exists($mp3)) {
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .basename($mp3). '"' );
header('Content-length: '. filesize($mp3));
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
readfile($mp3);
header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
exit;
}
```

Not knowing what connection.php looks like, I think this will work. Give it a try!

Comment: I'm now getting error when I try to download Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\powerbeatz\file.php:20 @techcyclist

Comment: Yep so it doesnt like how im creating the mysqli parameter. Can you share connection.php and hide the connection parameters?

Comment: OK, try the above. I'm using $songid in the same way you were already doing in your first query. So since SQL injection is a risk, make sure to look into changing how that's being done.

Comment: Should i still send my connection.php @techcyclist

Comment: No, I decided to use the same method that was being used there. So I don't need to see that.

Comment: I tried what u gave me but it give this error Notice: Undefined index: downloads in download_page.php @techcyclist

Comment: I see, because you are already doing this: <?php echo $row['song']; ?> I assumed I could do the same to get the download count (<?php echo $row['downloads']; ?>). How are you getting $row['song'] on that page? Is there more code on that page that you aren't showing?

Comment: Yes please i have code above my doctype which i have just added now so u can check @techcyclist

Comment: OK so here we just need to add downloads: $sql = 'SELECT filename, album_art, song, song_id, artist FROM homemp3 WHERE 
song_id ='.$songid; ..... I'll do this above in the code.

Comment: Now it should work. You were selecting some fields from the table, just not the downloads. So now it will do that.

Comment: I have added downloads to my $sql variable but it doesn't update when i download click to download a file @techcyclist

Comment: No it doesn't please @techcyclist

Comment: try this for testing, right after the $downloads = $conn->query($update);
 add this: dd($downloads);

Comment: Sorry that's in laravel use this instead:

Comment: var_dump($downloads);
die();

Comment: I have to go for now. Back later.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd() @techcyclist

Comment: it says bool(false) @techcyclist

Comment: Please where exactly should i put it @techcyclist

Comment: After $downloads = $conn->query($update); add this:

$updated = $stmt->affected_rows;
var_dump($updated); die();

Comment: Still error Notice: Undefined variable: stmt and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object @techcyclist

Comment: OK, when you go to the download page and then check the DB, is the download count higher? If not then the issue is that somehow the update isn't running.

Comment: So how do i solve this issue please, because it works when i query it in my database but don't know why it doesn't work in my scripts @techcyclist

Comment: Hi Josh if the database shows the correct updated downloads, but it's not showing on the page, then $sql = 'SELECT filename, album_art, downloads, song, song_id, artist FROM homemp3 WHERE song_id ='.$songid; somehow isn't functioning properly. Otherwise I'm not sure why it wouldn't show on the page correctly.